# Can't access another AWS ec2 instance (in the same subnet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I'm setting up an AWS VPC with both private and public subnets. In public subnets, I created 2 instances: one as bastion host and one as a web server. For the web server, I only want to make port 80 open to public, but SSH access needs to done through the bastion host.

I created 2 paris of SSH keys. One is dedicated for public access to bastion host from external. Another is for private SSH access from bastion host to the web server (and all other instances that will be created in the private subnets).

At the moment, I can SSH to bastion host as expected. But from bastion host, I can't SSH into the web server, althoug I have the right inbound securiy rules. In order to find the issue, I did some more tests. First, I expanded the inbound rule on the web server to allow public SSH access. Once I do so, I can SSH into the web server from external. Second, I add rules for ICMP traffic both from bastion host only and from public (0.0.0.0/0). But again, I can ping from external, but not from bastion host.

```
Below is the webserver (IP: 191.100.0.56) inbound and outbound rules. Note that IP 191.100.0.162 is the bastion host IP.

[WebServer Inbound rules]
Ports   Protocol    Source                      
22      tcp         191.100.0.160/32, 0.0.0.0/0 

[WebServer Outbound rules]
Ports   Protocol    Source  
All     All         0.0.0.0/0

The subnet ACL is default which is Allow ALL for both inbound and outbound.

100     ALL Traffic     ALL         ALL         0.0.0.0/0       ALLOW       
*       ALL Traffic     ALL         ALL         0.0.0.0/0       DENY
```

I'm wondering where could be the problem? This is a bit strange to me. Why I can access (SSH or ping) from public, but not from the bastion host?

Comment: Are the 191.* IP addresses public or private IP addresses?

Comment: From the bastion, are you using ssh and ping to the *private IP* of the web server? What does "I can't SSH into the web server" mean? What are the symptoms or error messages?

Comment: @WarrenG 191.* is private IP

Comment: @jarmod from the bastion, I'm trying to SSH/ping to the private IP of the web server. "I can't SSH into the web server" means the connection timeout for SSH. When I tried to ping, there is no receiving packet.

Comment: Make sure the bastion security group egress rules are the defaults. Remove any network ACL modifications you may have made (use the defaults). Modify the web server security group ingress rules to allow inbound All ICMP from the bastion SG. Then ping the web server private IP from the bastion.

Comment: I found the issue. Somehow the outbound rules on the bastion host was deleted. :( After adding that back, I'm good now. Thanks guys for all your prompt response and comment.

Comment: @jarmod I didn't see your comment earlier, but you got the point!